# Checking for a successful charge using Stripe for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, payment-processing, webhooks

*Context:*

I am using Stripe checkout to accept one-time payment in rails.
I have a charges controller as shown below.
I was initially using stripe webhook to listen to charge.succeeded, but running into some issues due to the async nature of webhooks.
My I have moved the business logic to the controller.
If the customer charge is a success, then I  save the customer and some other details to the db.

*My question:*

Is this check enough to ensure that a charge is successful ?

```
if charge["paid"] == true
```

The Stripe documentation for Stripe::Charge.create states, "
Returns a charge object if the charge succeeded. Raises an error if something goes wrong. A common source of error is an invalid or expired card, or a valid card with insufficient available balance."

*My ChargesController:*

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents

    @amount = 100
    temp_job_id = cookies[:temp_job_id]
    customer_email =  TempJobPost.find_by(id: temp_job_id).company[:email]
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => customer_email,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd',
      :metadata => {"job_id"=> temp_job_id}
    )
    # TODO: charge.paid or charge["paid"]
    if charge["paid"] == true
     #Save customer to the db
    end

    # need to test this and refactor this using begin-->rescue--->end
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path

  end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's all you need to do. If the charge succeeded, Stripe will return a Charge object, and you can check its `paid` parameter. If the charge failed, we'd throw an exception.

Cheers,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Comment: So, technically, he doesn't need to do `if charge["paid"]` correct? Because if the charge fails, the exception will be raised and that section of the code won't be executed?

Comment: Can we rely on the status = "succeeded" as well?